# why cant upload image using multipart?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, multipart

i have problem with uploading image to server using multipart when uploading the image to sever the response is success but it get with null response and nothing uploaded when i trying to send data without using multipart send email or name data sent successfully but when i try to sent anything using part nothing sent to the server in the same api

```
  @Multipart
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"})
    @POST("profile")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part image

    );


  void data_1(File file) {

        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);

        Retrofit retrofits = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Base_url).
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        networkis networkis = retrofits.create(www.gift_vouchers.com.NetworkLayer.networkis.class);


        Call<ResponseBody> call = networkis.upload("Bearer " + new saved_data().get_token(UserInfoModelViewFactory.context)
                , body);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                new utils().dismiss_dialog(UserInfoModelViewFactory.context);
                Log.e("response_is", "" + response.message() + "dcd" + response.isSuccessful());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                new utils().dismiss_dialog(UserInfoModelViewFactory.context);
                Log.e("error", t.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling `data_1()`? Where is the `File` parameter coming from?

Comment: from fragment  UserInfoModelView.data_1(file);   i printed file in tag no problem with it